# Find the missing sides and angles in following case for a spherical triangle ABC:

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

$\bf{QUESTION}$: Find the missing sides and angles in following case for a spherical triangle ABC:

$$a)a=60°,\beta=90°, \gamma=75° $$

So, if I am right my book says sides are denoted by lowercase letters. My book uses $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ for planes but online it says it is sometimes used as angles, which I assume in this case it is because the question asks for missing sides and angles. However, I am encountering any problems probably due to confusion.

For a:
$$a)a=60°,\beta=90°, \gamma=75° $$

I used:
$$\cos(a)=\frac{\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\beta)\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\beta) \sin(\gamma)}$$
and plugged in:
$$\cos(60°)=\frac{\cos(\alpha)-\cos(90°)\cos(75°)}{\sin(90°) \sin(75°)}$$
which means:
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\cos(\alpha)-0}{\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}}=\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}}=\frac{4\cos(\alpha)}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}=4\cos(\alpha)$$
$$2(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})=\cos(\alpha)$$
$$\cos^{-1}(2\sqrt{6}+2\sqrt{2})=\alpha$$

So if I did it correct, do I just leave $\alpha$ like that? Or is it possible to find $\alpha$ without a calculator? If I had to guess, it would be some trig identity.

Also, I would have to find side b and side c. So, I would calculate b and c using the law of cosines as well.

So it would be:
$$\cos(b)=\frac{\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha) \sin(\gamma)}$$

and:

$$\cos(c)=\frac{\cos(\gamma)-\cos(\beta)\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\beta) \sin(\alpha)}$$

is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would interpret the symbols $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ as angles
between the sides, and $a$ as the arc length of a side.

I know of two sets of formulas that might be called the spherical law of cosines.
You can find both of them on the page for 
[spherical trigonometry at Wolfram MathWorld.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTrigonometry.html)
One set of formulas they call the cosine rule for sides:

$$\cos a = \cos b \cos c + \sin b \sin c \cos\alpha$$

(with corresponding formulas with $\cos b$ and $\cos c$, respectively, on the left).
The other set of formulas they call the cosine rule for angles:

$$\cos\alpha = -\cos\beta \cos\gamma + \sin\beta \sin\gamma \cos a$$

(with corresponding formulas with $\cos\beta$ and $\cos\gamma$, respectively, on the left).
You can easily put any of these formulas in a format like the one you have used;
from the cosine rule for angles you would end up with

$$\cos a = \frac{\cos\alpha + \cos\beta \cos\gamma}{\sin\beta \sin\gamma}.$$

Note the "$+$" operation in this formula where you have "$-$".
It turns out this has no effect on your result, since the right-hand operand
turns out to be zero.
Where you make a misstep is here:

> $$\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}=4\cos(\alpha)$$
>   $$2(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})=\cos(\alpha)$$

You need to divide *both* sides of the first equation by $4$, so the second equation
should have been 
$$\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{8} = \cos\alpha.$$
One way you might notice the error is that $2(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}) > 1$,
meaning it cannot be the cosine of any real-valued angle.

The result is not a "nice" angle like $60$ degrees or $75$ degrees, so
either you give a calculator's approximation or you leave it as an expression
involving $\cos^{-1}$.

You *could* find the other two sides of the triangle using law of cosines,
or you could use the Law of Sines for a spherical triangle, which is
relatively easy to remember:

$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin\beta}{\sin b} = \frac{\sin\gamma}{\sin c}.$$

That's actually three equations, two of which allow you to solve for your 
unknown sides $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Oops, made an arithmetic error, usually happens but thanks for the insights. I shall now proceed and go fix my mistakes.